# typedef syntax explanation in dart

Tags: dart, typedef

```
typedef  car = void Function(String name, String type);
typedef String car (String name, String type);
```

What is the difference between this two syntaxes of typedef?

Answer (score 0):

From the Dart language specification:

> Note that the type alias syntax without ‘=’ can only express function types, and it cannot express the type of a generic function. When such a type alias is generic, it always expresses a family of non-generic function types. These restrictions exist because that syntax was defined before generic functions were added to Dart.

https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.2.pdf

So in short, the syntax of your second example is from before generic functions was introduced in Dart and the syntax are therefore deprecated.